# Azure Cognitive Search Performance

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

If the index data and schema remains constant in Azure cognitive search, Does the latency gets impacted by the presence of an additional filter in the query. Note that Due to the presence of limit field in the query, the presence/non-presence does not increase/decrease the number of records being returned.

If yes, Then how does it impacts the latency.

Answer (score 1):

Filters can improve or decrease latency depending on your dataset.

A filter which reduces the total number of documents that need to be scored will improve performance, especially in large datasets. However, some complex filters can decrease performance due to the work needed to filter out documents.

It is recommended to perform your own benchmarks given your dataset and filters to determine how it impacts latency for your service.